# Dimension of the subset of linear operators.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, operator-theory

Let $v$ be a fixed non-zero vector of an $n$-dimensional real vector space $V$. Let $P(v)$ be the subspace of the vector space of linear operators on $V$ consisting of those operators that admit  $v$ as an eigenvector. What is the dimension of $P(v)$ as a real vector space (in terms of $n)$?

I note that $$P(v)=\{T: \ T(v)=\lambda v, \ \lambda\in \mathbb{R}\}.$$
In terms of matrices, the dimension of $P(v)$ is same as the dimension of $$\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})\ | Av=\lambda v\ \text{for some} \ \lambda >0\}.$$ How to think about the dimension about this set. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the vector $v$ and complete it to a base of $V$.
In this basis a matrix $A$ that satisfies $Av=\lambda v$ will be of the form

$$A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda & \cdots & & & \\
    0 & \ddots &  &  \\
    0 & &  \\
    \vdots &  &  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
The only thing that needs to stay fixed to satisfy our conditions is the first column of $n-1$ zeroes. The other $n-1$ columns and $\lambda$ can change arbitrarly. The dimension of our space is then $n^2-n+1$.